# 2D rendering (matrices, specifically) in OpenGL ES 2.0 (Android)

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, orthographic

So I'm trying to render two moving quads, each at different locations. My shaders are as simple as possible (vertices are only transformed by the modelview-projection matrix, there's only one color).

Whenever I try and render something, I only end up with slivers of color! I've only done work with 3D rendering in OpenGL before so I'm having issues with 2D stuff.

Here's my basic rendering loop, simplified a bit (I'm using the Matrix manipulation methods provided by `android.opengl.Matrix` and `program` is a custom class I created that just calls `GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv()`):

```
Matrix.orthoM(projection, 0, 0, windowWidth, 0, windowHeight, -1, 1);
program.setUniformMatrix4f("Projection", projection);
```

At this point, I render the quads (this is repeated for each quad):

```
Matrix.setIdentityM(modelview, 0);
Matrix.translateM(modelview, 0, quadX, quadY, 0);
program.setUniformMatrix4f("ModelView", modelview);
quad.render(); // calls glDrawArrays
```

and all I see is a sliver of the color each quad is! I'm at my wits end here, I've tried everything I can think of and I'm at the point where I'm screaming at my computer and tossing phones across the room. Anybody got any pointers? Am I using ortho wrong? I'm 100% sure I'm rendering everything at a Z value of 0. I tried using `frustumM` instead of `orthoM`, which made it so that I could see the quads but they would get totally skewed whenever they got moved, which makes sense if I correctly understand the way frustum works (it's more for 3D rendering, anyway).

If it makes any difference, I defined my viewport with

```
 GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight);
```

Where `windowWidth` and `windowHeight` are the same values that are pased to orthoM

*edit:* It might be worth noting that the `android.opengl.Matrix` methods take in an offset as the second parameter so that multiple matrices can be shoved into one array, so that'w what the first `0` is for

*another edit:* For reference, here's my vertex shader code:

```
uniform mat4 ModelView;
uniform mat4 Projection;

attribute vec4 vPosition;

void main() {
    mat4 mvp = Projection * ModelView; 
    gl_Position = vPosition * mvp;
}
```

*yet another edit:* I tried swapping `Projection * ModelView` with `ModelView * Projection` but now I just get some really funky looking shapes...

Answer (score 0):

mvp should be Proj*ModelView as you have it.

gl_Position should be mvp * vPosition, not the other way around as you show in your code there.

If that does not solve the problem, can you better describe the problem (an image might help)? Also consider posting more of your opengl code, in case the error is there. All the rest of the code you posted looks fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

I posted this over on gamedev.stackexchange.com and figured it out, [here
s a link](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/31821/2d-rendering-with-opengl-es-2-0-on-android-matrices-not-working)

Comment: For future reference, please don't cross post (or at the very least make a note of it in your question, so you don't waste our time).  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu